# Images of static google maps API doesn't load on flash (when running on server)

Tags: actionscript-3, google-maps

I've been using the static API for google maps and streetView on my flash (as3) application. There was not problem at all untill I uploaded it to a server. It started giving me sandbox violation errors and Error #2048.
I've tried loading crossDomain files and allowing domains with no success, also I couldn't make a proxy work.
My app was working before with the JS API but I need to improove it in a way that just my swf file runs without extra divs.

Comment: There's not enough information to answer. Please post some code.

Comment: Try using a packet sniffer like [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and see which crossdomains are being requested and 404'd or 200'd but without permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It's a crossdomain policy issue. You must be loading SWF's from another domain or your SWF is being loaded by a domain where the SWF does not reside. For example, your SWF is on www.a.com and is loading a swf from www.b.com. Your SWF needs to load www.b.com/crossdomain.xml and that XML file must grand your SWF permissions. In the event that www.b.com is loading your SWF from www.a.com, you must supply a crossdomain.xml file on the same domain as your SWF (and preferably directory). See more here:

http://curtismorley.com/2007/08/31/flash-cs3-flex-2-as3-error-2148/